# jQuery - How to hide an element that is not contain the specific class

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have the html code below, I want to ONLY display the "p" element with class="go-1", it is not good to write the statement to hide the element with class="2", class="3", class="100"... how can I write it in a smart way?

The statement can be say as "if "p" class not equal to "go-1" then hide it"
Thanks

```
<p class="go-1"></p>
<p class="go-2"></p>
<p class="go-3"></p>
...
<p class="go-100"></p>
<p class="go-1"></p>
<p class="go-2"></p>
<p class="go-3"></p>
...
<p class="go-100"></p>
<p class="go-1"></p>
<p class="go-2"></p>
<p class="go-3"></p>
...
<p class="go-100"></p>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just use `:not()`:

```
$('p:not(.go-1)').hide();
```

Comment: I wish CSS was as simple as jQuery selectors... Most of jQuery's selectors are quite intuitive (like `:first-child`, `:last`, `:animating`, `:hidden`, etc.), so it's just knowing which ones are there and which ones aren't. Look at the selector list here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Sometimes CSS is as simple as Jquery. Just not all the time, and especially not so if you have to deal with sub-standard browsers or backwards-compatibility. Reference of CSS selectors: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors